# Reading raw (binary?) Tiedot (NOSQL / JSON) data from Onionscan using Python

Tags: python, json, tiedot

I've been trying out [Onionscan](https://github.com/s-rah/onionscan) recently after following a [tutorial](http://www.automatingosint.com/blog/2016/07/dark-web-osint-with-python-and-onionscan-part-one/) on building an Onionscan Scraper using a Python wrapper. Since the tutorial was written Onionscan has shifted from storing all data in JSON files, to storing some of it in a database built using Tiedot.

I am trying to find a way of taking one of the files which has no extension, simply named `dat_0` and parsing it using Python.

Looking at `dat_0` in macOS Textedit I get the following...
[image: dat_0 as displayed by Textedit]

Whilst Sublime Text displays it as...
[image: dat_0 as displayed in Sublime text]

I have been trying to work out how to parse this file using Python. I'm presuming from Tiedot's docs and the view via Textedit that it uses JSON structures, but I've not had much luck.

```
import json
f = open('crawls/dat_0','rb')
data = json.dumps(f.read())

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

or

```
data = json.loads(f.read())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-21c335a72c11> in <module>()
----> 1 data = json.loads(f)

/Users/James/anaconda/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    310     if not isinstance(s, str):
    311         raise TypeError('the JSON object must be str, not {!r}'.format(
--> 312                             s.__class__.__name__))
    313     if s.startswith(u'\ufeff'):
    314         raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Does anyone...
a) Know what this file is?
b) Know how I might successfully parse it to make the data usable in Python?

Comment: Why is there a Go tag on your question ? You are asking help for help in Python, the fact OnionScan is written in Go is not related yo your issue.

Comment: @WilliamPoussier I wasn't entirely sure whether the data I'm trying to parse may be a fairly standard format in the Go community as it was produced using Tiedot. I thought that if it was it would be recognised fairly quickly by those familiar with Go, but not necessarily by those familiar with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that finds this in the future, I found a solution myself. I used [Kaitai Struct](http://kaitai.io/) to create a binary parser for the Tiedot file structure. Kaitai can create parsers for a multitude of languages so it's quite a useful tool

The Kaitai structure I used to generate the parser is...

```
meta:
  id: parser
seq:
  - id: records
    type: record
    repeat: eos
types:
  record:
    seq:
    - id: validity
      type: s1
    - id: allocated
      type: s8le
    - id: document
      type: str
      encoding: utf-8
      terminator: 1
      eos-error: false
```